# How to separate a date in c programming c date functions

Tags: c, function, date

Write a function GetDate with the following prototype:

```
void GetDate (char * date, int * dp, int * mp, int * yp);
```

Function accepts a string parameter and date showing date as follows:

```
dd - mmm - yy
```

two digits to mark the day, three-letter shortcut to mark the month and year in two digits.
The function is to separate the components and deliver them by reference to a numerical format.
An example of running the program that calls the function

```
Enter a date as 

dd-mmm-yy:
28-Aug-63

Day = 28
Month = 8
Year = 63
```

the code i make and isn't working is:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void GetDate (char *date, int *dp, int *mp, int *yp);

void main()
{
char date, month[3];
int day[2],year[2];
printf("Enter a date as dd-mmm-yy:");
separator(s) [ , -] 
gets(day);

gets(month);
gets(year);

strcpy(date,day);
strcpy(date,"-");
strcpy(date,month);
strcpy(date,"-");
strcpy(date,year);

puts(date)

}
void GetDate (char *date, int *dp, int *mp, int *yp)
{
char date;
int dp,mp,yp;
scanf("%d-%d-%d",dp,mp,yp);
date[9]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we are no coding service here. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27874555/edit) your question and add what you have tried to solve your task.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "Please write my code for me."

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can follow the below mentioned steps to create a fully-functional code.

1. select the separator(s) [ , `-`] as delimiter character(s).
2. Parse the incoming string using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).
3. Get the *tokenized* output, and as per the prescribed format, store it into appropriate variable. If it has to be directly represented with *integer* [as for `date` amd `year`], convert the token using [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), otherwise, as for a string format[for `month`], you can use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to compare with the *predefined* month value and store the *predefined* corresponding integer value.
4. Repeat step 3 for all the members of the prescribed format or till the returned token is NULL, whichever is earlier.

Optionally, you may want to verify a few things in your code, e.g,

- NULL check for incoming pointers.
- Validity of the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sscanf.

```
sscanf(date,"%d-%s-%d",&date,month,&year);
```

Then in one array of pointers, have the month name and compare that with the month variable using that get the numeric value of that month.

```
char *mon[]={ "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
```

Using the loop you can get the numeric value. After that Using that one you can print the month in integer.

Comment: `sscanf("28-Aug-63","%d-%s-%d",&date,month,&year);` will **not work**.  `date` will get the value `28`, `month` will be filled with `"Aug-63"` and `year` will remain as-is.  Not checking the `sscanf()` result nor limiting the width of data into `month` are additional problems.